# Menu not showing tooltip in C# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

i have this code

```
<MenuItem Header="{localization:Translate NewChart}" ToolTip="Ctrl+h"
          Command="{Binding AddChartCommand}">
    <MenuItem.Background>
        <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="0.768" RadiusY="0.783">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF2b2b2b" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF515151" Offset="0.388"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </MenuItem.Background>
</MenuItem>
```

I don't understand why i can't see the toottip when i take mouse over the menu item.
(this works fine on windows 7 but it doesn't work on bloomberg terminal.)

Comment: Works fine at my end. Tried in small sample.

Comment: it works fine on windows7 but when i do this on Bloomberg Terminal i don't know why its not working.

Answer (score 0):

Try the extended version:

```
<MenuItem Header="{localization:Translate NewChart}" Command="{Binding AddChartCommand}">
    <MenuItem.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip>Ctrl+h</ToolTip>
    </MenuItem.ToolTip>
    <MenuItem.Background>
            <RadialGradientBrush RadiusX="0.768" RadiusY="0.783">
            <GradientStop Color="#FF2b2b2b" Offset="1"/>
            <GradientStop Color="#FF515151" Offset="0.388"/>
        </RadialGradientBrush>
    </MenuItem.Background>
</MenuItem>
```